# Basic cypress example is aborted after page visit

Tags: cypress

My basic test is aborted after the reddit page is visited.
Could you tell me how to keep the log window open?


cy.wait() is also not working. Could you tell me why?

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('My First Test', () => {
  it('Does not do much!', () => {
    expect(true).to.equal(true)

    cy.visit('www.reddit.com')
    cy.url().contains('reddit')
    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.log("hello")
    cy.wait(10000)
  })
})
```

Comment: Is the page not loading or is the test runner crashing/closing?

Comment: Test runner is closing after www.reddit.com was loading